# How to plot bar plot with Chinese names in input file?

Tags: r, unicode, utf-8

I want to plot a barplot from an input file having Chinese characters.

```
木材   2   2 
表     3   4
笔     4   2 
垃圾桶  5   6 
杯     6   3
```

I expect the output like Excel with Chinese names as y labels and legends. How can I implement it in R?
[image]

After changing locale to simplified chinese i get the following graph.

```
sessionInfo()
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=zh_CN.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=zh_CN.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=zh_CN.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_CN.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] XML_3.9-4
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing your locale to chinese? Are the necessary fonts installed?

Comment: I just installed Chineese simplified font and setlocale to chineese simplified but still i get different font as how in above image.

Answer (score 1):

What problems do you have when you try to get this barplot? It works for me, at least what concerns the Chinise characters. Try

```
mydata = matrix( c( 2:6, c( 2,4,2,6,3 ) ), nrow= 2 )
mylabs = c( "木材", "表", "笔", "垃圾桶", "杯" )
barplot( mydata, beside=T, horiz= "T", names.arg= mylabs, las= 1, col= c( "red", "blue" ) )
```

[image]

Maybe you have problems when you try to save the plot as pdf. In that case, try jpeg:

```
jpeg( "plotname.jpg" )
barplot( mydata, beside=T, horiz= "T", names.arg= mylabs, las= 1, col= c( "red", "blue" ) )
dev.off()
```

Comment: I used your code but i found printed characters are not chineese.

Comment: In that case, something is rotten with your R installation, and you will need to provide R version, operating system version etc. etc. in your question (not in this comment, because I can't help you with a messed R installation).

Comment: @Manish Please edit the output of `sessionInfo()` into your question.

Comment: Still pblm is chineese characters are not printed, some other characters gets printed.

Comment: January's solution works for me also, but I'm on Windows 7, not linux.

Comment: May i know which parameter do i need to set in R for getting chineese characters.

Comment: @Ronald, pls help me i have already changed my system's setting.

Comment: I generated 2 plots one pdf and other png. png image is ok but on pdf there is not text except .......... only.