# How to plot R barplot with Chinese text by setting locale on Ubuntu?

Tags: r, unicode, plot

This is with ref to my previous question on this forum, [How to plot bar plot with Chinese names in input file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892335/how-to-plot-bar-plot-with-chinese-names-in-input-file)

I have already edited my `sessionInfo` like so:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
[3] LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=zh_CN.UTF-8    
[5] LC_MONETARY=zh_CN.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=zh_CN.UTF-8   
[7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
[9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_CN.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
```

But when i run my script `a.txt`

**a.txt**

```
x <- read.csv(textConnection("名称,类,学生  
木材,2,2 
表,3,4 
笔,4,2 
垃圾桶,5,6 
杯,6,3"), header = TRUE) 
rownames(x) <- x[,1] 
x <- x[,-1] 
barplot(t(x), horiz = TRUE, beside = TRUE, legend.text = TRUE, xlab="名称类学生") 

source("a.txt",encoding="UTF-8")
```

I get some weird characters instead of Chinese characters (see image below). How can I avoid them?

[image]

Comment: It works perfectly on my system. What OS are you using? Notably, I have R 2.15.1, but I doubt that this is the problem.

Comment: I m using R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22) and ubuntu OS 64 bit. Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Comment: I just tested on windows PC. It works fine....... But on linux it has got some pblm.

Comment: I have tested it on two versions of Ubuntu (10.04 and 12.04) and it works perfectly.

Comment: Try starting R with the default locale: `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 R`

Comment: Ok, Now i can generate on windows png but when i try to generate pdf, i get some pblm. Text on pdf is not blank only ........ is there. How can i generate chinease characters on pdf?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18199/discussion-between-manish-and-january)

Comment: Did you solve this problem, I asked a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18386727/r-plot-title-encoding