# How to plot chinese characters on pdf?

Tags: r, pdf, unicode, plot

My question is related to my previous question.

[How to plot bar plot with Chinese names in input file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892335/how-to-plot-bar-plot-with-chinese-names-in-input-file)

I need to plot now chinese characters on pdf.

```
mydata = matrix( c( 2:6, c( 2,4,2,6,3 ) ), nrow= 2 )
mylabs = c( "木材", "表", "笔", "垃圾桶", "杯" )
barplot( mydata, beside=T, horiz= "T", names.arg= mylabs, las= 1, col= c( "red", "blue" ) )

pdf( "plotname.pdf" )
barplot( mydata, beside=T, horiz= "T", names.arg= mylabs, las= 1, col= c( "red", "blue" ) )
dev.off()
```

But on pdf only .... gets printed instead of Chinese names.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
cairo_pdf( "plotname.pdf" )
barplot( mydata, beside=T, horiz= "T", names.arg= mylabs, las= 1, col= c( "red", "blue" ) )
dev.off()
```

Comment: Ok, But i m getting following error message on my linux when i use cairo command failed to load cairo DLL

Comment: Dear Manish, something **is** wrong with your Ubuntu. I also use 10.04, default interface, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as yours (I'm on a Mac with R 2.14.2 and locale settings in french).
I managed to get around by specifying the font family "GB1" (Simplified Chinese) in the `pdf` call:

```
pdf( "plotname.pdf" , family="GB1")
barplot( mydata, beside=T, horiz= "T", names.arg= mylabs, las= 1, col= c( "red", "blue" ) )
dev.off()
```

Comment: This is very useful but in order to see the chinese characters, i need to install chinese font for adobe reader.