# Cannot write chinese text using CairoPDF in R

Tags: r, plot, multilingual

I am using cairo pdf as suggested in my previous question

[How to plot chinese characters on pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948701/how-to-plot-chinese-characters-on-pdf)

for generating chinese text on R.

```
library(Cairo)
mydata = matrix( c( 2:6, c( 2,4,2,6,3 ) ), nrow= 2 )
mylabs = c( "木材", "表", "笔", "垃圾桶", "杯" )
CairoPDF("Report_chinese.pdf", family="GB1")
barplot( mydata, beside=T, horiz= "T", names.arg= mylabs, las= 1, col= c( "red", "blue" ) )
dev.off()
```

But there is no chinese text on bar plot. How can i fix this pblm?

Regards

Comment: I think in the previous questions you've been suggested `cairo_pdf` not `CairoPDF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cairo_pdf()` works for me:

```
mydata = matrix( c( 2:6, c( 2,4,2,6,3 ) ), nrow= 2 )
mylabs = c( "木材", "表", "笔", "垃圾桶", "杯" )
cairo_pdf("Report_chinese.pdf")
barplot( mydata, beside=T, horiz= "T", names.arg= mylabs, las= 1, col= c( "red", "blue" ) )
dev.off()
```

If you want to use the `Cairo` library, you have to first define a font that has the CJK glyphs (**EDIT:** per request in comments, this example uses different fonts for labels and title):

```
library(Cairo)
CairoFonts(regular="AR PL UKai CN:Book", bold="Century Schoolbook L:Italic")
CairoPDF("Report_chinese.pdf")
barplot( mydata, beside=T, horiz= "T", names.arg= mylabs, las= 1, col= c( "red", "blue" ) )
mtext("This is the title", side=3, line=1, font=2)
dev.off()
```

Note that the arguments to `CairoFonts()` are just arbitrary pointers: I have used the `bold=` argument to specify an italic typeface, and access it using `font=2` in the call to `mtext()` (see the `font` argument in `?par`).  Be sure to substitute "AR PL UKai CN:Book" and "Century Schoolbook L:Italic" for fonts that you actually have on your system.

If you don't like that method, you can get the same result by calling `CairoFonts()` multiple times:

```
CairoFonts(regular="AR PL UKai CN:Book")
CairoPDF("Report_chinese.pdf")
barplot( mydata, beside=T, horiz= "T", names.arg= mylabs, las= 1, col= c( "red", "blue" ) )
CairoFonts(regular="Century Schoolbook L:Italic")
mtext("This is the title", side=3, line=1) #implicit argument: font=1
dev.off()
```

[image: barplot of sample data with Chinese category labels and different font for overall title]

Comment: Thanks! CairoFonts is very good solution. One more thing, how can i keep two different fonts. Like for title Droid Sans Fallback using CairoFonts(regular='Droid Sans Fallback') and for legends normal chinese text (not bold). I used CairoFonts(regular='GB1') before generating legend, legend("bottomright", c("垃圾桶","木材"), cex=1.5, bty="n", fill = c(rgb(.059, .412, .659),rgb(.537, .769, .933))); but does not seem to be working

Comment: You can call `CairoFonts()` multiple times to change the font midway through the plotting.  Alternatively, you can define the various typefaces as the `italic` and `bold` arguments of `CairoFonts` (even if they aren't in fact italic or bold), and then trigger their use with the R font codes (see `?par` and look for `'font'`).

Comment: Can u pls post an example. This seems to be bit difficult for me.