# Cannot display Chinese on a plot in R

Tags: r, utf-8

This is related to an old question: [How to plot bar plot with Chinese names in input file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892335/how-to-plot-bar-plot-with-chinese-names-in-input-file/43508615#43508615)

I am still having the same problem after trying various ways suggested by users.

My settings:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Then I did:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", locale="UTF-8")
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "UTF-8")
mydata = matrix( c( 2:6, c( 2,4,2,6,3 ) ), nrow= 2 )
mylabs = c( "木材", "表", "笔", "垃圾桶", "杯" )
barplot( mydata, beside=T, horiz= "T", names.arg= mylabs, las= 1, col= c( "red", "blue" ) )
```

The error I got was:

```
Error in axis(if (horiz) 2 else 1, at = at.l, labels = names.arg, lty = axis.lty,  : 
  could not find any X11 fonts
Check that the Font Path is correct.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In (function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  :
  locale not supported by Xlib: some X ops will operate in C locale
2: In (function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  :
  X cannot set locale modifiers
```

I am using OS X Yosemite 10.10.5.

uname -a

Darwin mxmac.local 14.5.0 Darwin Kernel Version 14.5.0: Fri Feb 17 10:33:20 PST 2017; root:xnu-2782.50.9.1.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Tried "enc2utf8" as well, but got the same error.

Comment: It's very font- (and locale- and graphics device-) dependent. For me, adding `family = 'Arial Unicode MS'` to `barplot` did the trick, or use another suitable font.

Comment: Also, `"UTF-8"` probably won't work for your locale; you'll need to use a localized variant, e.g. `"en_US.UTF-8"`

Comment: How to add "Arial Unicode MS" to the family? 

I tried "en_US.UTF-8". It didn't give an error, but the Chinese characters were still not shown properly -- they looked gibberish.

Comment: Just add it as a parameter to `barplot`. You'd need that particular font (which is fairly common due to Microsoft) installed, but most any font with the necessary CJK characters should work fine.

Comment: I installed the font in R, and checked "Font Book" to verify "Arial Unicode MS" was installed on my Mac. But, still, the characters were not displayed property.